# React router-firebase private route with reactContext

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, react-router

I have this user context wit useEffect for firebase authentication. The whole app is wrapped around this.

```
export const UserProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState()
  useEffect(() => {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      setCurrentUser(user)
    })
  }, [])

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={currentUser}>{children}</UserContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

In my component, I check if the user is authenticated, and I use router history to redirect the user if not.

```
const history = useHistory()
const currentUser = useContext(UserContext)
  const handleRedirect = () => {
    return history.push('/login')
  }
  return (
    <>
      {currentUser ? (
        <div>
          <MiniDrawer></MiniDrawer>
          <Container maxWidth="md">
            <h1>
              Hello {currentUser.displayName}
            </h1>
            <Container>
              <h2>Team Activity</h2>
            </Container>
          </Container>
        </div>
      ) : (
        handleRedirect()
      )}
    </>
```

Whenever I reload the page and I am logged in it will first execute the **handleredirect** method and then it will go to the login Page for like half a second) specified in this method and it renders the correct component (first in the condition). What to do about it? It seems that it takes a while for the app to realize if it user exists or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
useEffect(() => { 
    setTimeout(() => {

        fire.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
            this.setState( { stateChanged: true } )
        });

   }, 1000)
}, [])
```